# Is it OK to create new branches for every little change in my code?

Tags: git, github

I've been using Git for around 6 months, but I'm not totally sure if I'm doing it right, for example I have a new project:

```sh
git init
git add *
git commit -m "new project"
```

Then I continue coding until a finish a feature (e.g Login form) so I:

```sh
git checkout -b "v1.1"
git add *  # to add new files
git commit -m "login form done"
```

I add another feature (e.g Navigation menu):

```sh
git checkout -b "v1.2"
git add *  # to add new files
git commit -m "Navigation menu done"
```

Sometimes I create new branches for little things like 1 line of code (e.g `background-color: blue` in my the css file):

```sh
git checkout -b "v1.3"
git commit -m "body background color changed"
```

I do it like that because if I want to go back to a state when the color was different I will just `git checkout v1.2`

Is it the right way to do it? Or there is another way to go back to a different state without creating new branches every time?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/202432/what-does-branching-is-free-mean-in-git

Comment: yes, it's okay create branches

Comment: You might want to use tags instead, if all you need are easy ways to refer to particular commits.

Comment: You don't appear to be merging your branches back to `master` (which, given the nature of the way you use them, would just be fast-forward merges, making your branches act a lot like tags).

Comment: Well I didn't know tags existed, so I'll be using tags now, thank you guys ♥

Comment: This might actually be a good question for [SoftwareEngineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). This is not so much a technical problem as it is a conceptual question about version control.

Answer (score 5):

There's no right and wrong here. Branches are incredibly lightweight (a branch is just a name, you can hardly get smaller than that). So no harm is done by your approach.

But I would just ask you: are you aware of commands like `git revert` and `git reset`? The point is that if you know what commit made a certain change, you can undo it with those commands. You don't need an individual *branch* to perform an undo. In some ways, having the extra branch makes effective undo harder.

---

The purpose of a branch is more like, "I'm going to be working on something and I have no idea how this is going to work out, so I want to be able to make many changes in many places over a long time without necessarily marring my existing code."

Another advantage of a branch is that you can swap the state of your code back and forth between branches without penalty (`switch`, née `checkout`).

If you don't need that for each of your changes, you might not need individual branches.

Answer (score 0):

There is no necessity in creating new branch, since you commit your changes. Git allows you to checkout between your commits, with `git checkout [commit_hash]`. From this point you can create a new branch and apply all the changes there. If you want to return into current branch - just run `git checkout [your_branch]`.

Also, if you want to get those hashes for commits: `git log`.